# loging popup goes to overflow

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

How do I stop my popup from going into the overflow?

It's a simple sign up div, I got off getboostrap.com

See this picture:

[image]

css is below

```
.dropdown-menu {
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: -200px;
z-index: 1000;
display: none;min-width: 10rem;
padding: 0.5rem 0;
margin: 0.125rem 0 0;
font-size: 1rem;
color: #868e96;`
```

code is

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdowns" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">

            <img src="~/images/account.png" />
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdowns">
            <form class="px-4 py-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleDropdownFormEmail1">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleDropdownFormEmail1" placeholder="email@example.com">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleDropdownFormPassword1">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleDropdownFormPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="dropdownCheck">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="dropdownCheck">
                        Remember me
                    </label>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
            </form>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">New around here? Sign up</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Forgot password?</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: While your post isn't set up properly ([see the MCVE guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), try replacing `left: -200px;` by `right: 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you need to add the class `.dropdown-menu-right` to the `.dropdown-menu` to right align the drop-down menu.

Notice: This does not require any custom css.

Click the "run code snippet" button below and expand to full page:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
   <div class="container">
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
       <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
           <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
       </button>

       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
           <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
               <li class="nav-item active">
                   <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
               </li>
               <li class="nav-item">
                   <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
               </li>
           </ul>

           <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
               <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                   <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdowns" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">

                       <img src="https://placehold.it/24" />
                   </a>
                   <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdowns">
                       <form class="px-4 py-3">
                           <div class="form-group">
                               <label for="exampleDropdownFormEmail1">Email address</label>
                               <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleDropdownFormEmail1" placeholder="email@example.com">
                           </div>
                           <div class="form-group">
                               <label for="exampleDropdownFormPassword1">Password</label>
                               <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleDropdownFormPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                           </div>
                           <div class="form-check">
                               <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="dropdownCheck">
                               <label class="form-check-label" for="dropdownCheck">
                                   Remember me
                               </label>
                           </div>
                           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
                       </form>
                       <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">New around here? Sign up</a>
                       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Forgot password?</a>
                   </div>
               </li>
           </ul>

       </div>
   </div>

</nav>
```